# How to use websockets in Next js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, server, next.js, server-side-rendering

I am using Next js for server sider rendering of my application. However, I also need to connect to the Gamesparks library(for authentication) which uses websockets. Every time I try to add my script to the head tag, I get errors that it's not working. Is it possible to use websockets in Next js? I've seen a lot about socket io, and was considering it, but I'd have to re-write the attached library. I'm also curious, should I instead attempt to do my own backend Express server to manage these connections?

As you can probably tell, I'm new to web-development so any resources or suggestions would be appreciated!

The error message from the browser is http://localhost:3000/gamesparks/gamesparks-rt.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)

Comment: Remember on Stack Overflow the number one thing is to be very specific, show us **exactly what errors you got** and don't leave us guessing. Then show us the code that generated those errors. Your browser is probably giving you information that's indicating a problem, but that problem is not something as simple as "error not working".

Comment: Just edited to include the error! I wasn't sure if it would help, but you're right I should've included it anyway

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is almost always helpful.

That one implies it can't find that JavaScript file, so you'll need to figure out why. Is your server set up to serve static assets? [You'll need to configure this](https://expressjs.com/en/starter/static-files.html):

```
app.use(express.static('public'))
```

Where you've put that file in `public/gamesparks/gamesparks-rt.js` relative to your Express project.

This is what a 404-type error usually refers to: Your browser requested the file and was told it didn't exist. As Express won't serve up "static" files unless you tell it to, you'll need to configure it.

Comment: Hey, thanks for this! Just wanted to expand on how I actually found the answer if anyone has this same issue. You were right on the money with the fact that I needed to serve the static assets, however Next js has built in functionality for this ie the "static" folder in the root directory. I simply moved the files there, changed the link and it worked!